# Convert PowerPoint Slides into Single Infographics

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, image-processing, visualization

[Infographics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infographic) are graphic visual representations of information, data, or knowledge intended to present information quickly and clearly.

I have PowerPoint presentation with about 8-10 slides, this slides are well formatted with pretty good visualizations. I would like to convert them all into a single big Infographic image?

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that? I know how to convert individual slides to an image and then I can merge them all together into a single vertical image. But it is kind of tedious.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this today for some reason.

I'll paste a bit of VBA below that will do the job for you. It creates a second presentation the height of your original presentation * number of slides in your original, then pastes a copy of each original slide onto the one slide in the new presentation, one stacked neatly atop the other, in order.

One caveat:  PPT won't create slides of over 56" in either dimension, so make sure your slides won't cause an overflow. I haven't bothered to test for this in the VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeInfoGraphic()

Dim oInfoPres As Presentation
Dim oInfoSlide As Slide
Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim lTop As Long

Set oPres = ActivePresentation
Set oInfoPres = Presentations.Add
oInfoPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight = oPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight * oPres.Slides.Count
oInfoPres.Slides.AddSlide 1, oInfoPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(7) ' Blank slide

lTop = 0

For Each oSl In oPres.Slides
    oSl.Copy
    With oInfoPres.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)
        .Left = 0
        .Width = oInfoPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth
        .Top = lTop
        lTop = lTop + .Height
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much. This works really great, except, it reduces the quality of the PowerPoint slides. The text becomes more blurry. I do not use very small texts either, but even the main title text becomes blurry. Is it possible to change the quality of the output slides?

Comment: Try changing ppPastePNG to ppPasteEMF for starters. But if you simply save the resulting slide as a raster format image, the resolution will be rather low. Have a look here for various ways of increasing the resolution (a page on the PPT FAQ that I maintain):
Improve PowerPoint's GIF, BMP, PNG, JPG export resolution
https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00052_Improve_PowerPoint-s_GIF-_BMP-_PNG-_JPG_export_resolution.htm

Comment: I changed the format to EMF, BTW it is actually `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`, the resulting images were way better than the PNG. It was very crisp. The only difference was when I exported as PNG, it left a slight edge effect to some big text. It is not very prominent, but still visible (if you care about it). 

I also followed your link to default `ExportBitmapResolution` to 300 DPi, through Regedit. I am using Office 2016. I am not sure, what difference it made. But, you have a very useful site there. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get the edge effect on the text (including JPG somewhere in the chain would explain it, but you're not doing that).  Note that you can export to a considerably higher resolution since you have 2016. In addition to modifying the registry, you can use Activepresentation.Slides(1).Export "c:\foldername\filename.PNG","PNG",WidthInPixels,HeightInPixels  Supply your own values for WidthInPixels and HeightInPixels (making sure that the ratio between them matches the width/height ratio of your presentation). You should be able to export to perhaps as much as 15,000 pixels high.

Comment: I will look into those. Really appreciate you sharing your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of a way to create a big vertical image from all the slides but as a workaround to get the screenshots of all the slides into one slide, you can use the zoom function.

You can go to Insert --> Zoom --> Summary Zoom. Select all the slides and click Insert. This gives you a section with one single slide with the screenshots of all the slides. You can resize them to fit and export this single slide as a png.

This would not would not give you a big image, the image would be the same size as the slide but you can change dimensions of the PowerPoint proportionally and use maximise to proportionally increase without affecting any elements in the slides. You can do this before carrying out the above summary zoom step. This could give you a bigger image.

Comment: Vishal, interesting approach. I did not know about the summary zoom. However, there are many steps for the work around. I guess, I will keep looking for a better faster, automated way. Thank you.